# Magento2: Call different list.phtml file in some category?

Tags: magento2, category, template, product-list, list.phtml

I want to customize catalog list page for some categories. 
I got the below link
[how to use different template file for category magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140312/how-to-use-different-template-file-for-category-magento-2)
But it needs separate xml for each category and the name should be catalog_category_view_id_{{id}}.xml .It is not possible in my case. How can I do it

Answer (score 1):

**Well not sure if you are looking for this. Seems too easy. Why not using this.**

`You can choose your theme, your layout, and even can customize it using layout update xml`

[image]