# How to change the layout for a particular category page

Tags: magento2, layout, category, xml, catalog-category

I know that for the category page or product view page, we can change the layout in `catalog_product_view.xml` or `catalog_category_view.xml`.

But how do I change exactly for a single particular category page?

Comment: Here is the answer to your question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/149768/57554

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the category page layout from admin in the Magento 2. Check [this](https://magento2tutorial.magestore.com/magento-2-change-category-page-layout-and-custom-theme/) link it will help you.

For Ex:- One category select `3 columns`

**Output**
[image]

And last one category select `2 columns with right bar`

**Output**

[image]

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: the link you sent is taking to 404

Comment: https://magento2tutorial.magestore.com/magento-2-change-category-page-layout-and-custom-theme/